# Using PHP to Generate Canvas

Tags: html, canvas

The problem I am having right now is trying to get PHP to make a canvas that the user can customize and save.  Here's what I mean:  I have a canvas that creates a cloud shape and the user can move it around and whatever.  That's all fine and dandy.  But, here's the problem; I can't seem to logically figure out how to use PHP to add in the user's name that they enter and put that on the cloud as regular text.  I would also like to be able to have users name some sort of collage that would be the bg-images of the canvas.  Additionally how would I be able to have the user ONLY be able to change the size, location, and pictures on the cloud without viewers being able to change that as well and integrate that into the canvas?

I'm sure there's a simple solution and I'll feel really stupid when I find it out.  But, anyway, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing something like this in PHP will be a bit difficult. By using PHP, you will still really be offloading to javascript via ajax.

EDIT: ignore the above. I'm not even sure it's possible as PHP is client side and js (canvas) is client side). But read below.

An alternative method would be to use node.js, or similar, to communicate with your server via javascript (canvas is really JS so why not stick with JS).

As for your other questions, once you can successfully talk to the server you can pass that info to the client - like whether the user/viewer has permission to see/view certain controls.

Comment: Now will that have any effect on latency?  I want the site to, of course, translate across all platforms with minimal waiting- even on mobile.

Comment: I'd image the data your sending/receiving will be minimal. You will likely use a json object/string. So in short, you will be fine with latency as you're just sending small amount of text.